What do scheduled flight times refer to?
Does the scheduled departure time refer to leaving the gate, leaving the ground, or something else?
Similarly, does the scheduled arrival time refer to the landing, arrival at the gate, or something else?
Obviously, variations will be common but I presume that the times refer to some event.

Probably depends a bit on the purpose. Flight plans, air traffic control, etc. only come into play close to departure and will vary a bit from day-to-day. Publicly posted departure and arrival times are more relevant from a legal point of view (especially in light of air passenger rights regulations). I recall reading that in the EU, it's the time the doors open and close that matters but I don't have an authoritative source at hand.

@Relaxed Doors closing and opening; that would be a good one.  Once, I very nearly missed a flight.  One of the cabin crew was at the door.  She said: "find your own seat" and immediately shut the door.

I’m voting to close this question because is belongs in https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

I'd defend it as a travel question (as well).  Surely, it's useful for a traveller to know what the times refer to.

why do you think it is useful to know? what will you do with that information? (knowing that, for departure you need to be at the gate before the gate closing time, and for landing the time depends a lot on the weather)

The top answer demonstrates that the times used are those relevant to travellers; they're also used by the aviation business.  From gate to airborne and vice versa can be very variable even at a given airport but of course estimates are used in setting schedules.  I was involved in collecting some relevant data nearly 30 years ago for a couple of UK airports (though ours was mainly to do with runway usage optimisation). In the flight information we had, the times used were those presented to passengers.

@njzk2 curiosity isn't exactly unknown in travel, but timing travel sickness medication for maximum effect (especially if a flight is one dose long) - they say take up to 30 minutes before travel, but also take a few minutes to take effect - would be an actual reason.

JonathanReez's answer also shows the possible relevance to travellers.

The Departure and Arrival times are estimates for when a plane expects to start maneuvering away from the departure gate and stop at the arrival gate respectively.
Prior to a flight, a Flight Plan must be submitted. These plans contain a huge array of fields regarding the flight. The International Civil Aviation Organization publishes and maintains documentation (Doc 4444) regarding the flight plan, its content and format. There are fields reserved for Departure and Arrival times, specified as estimates.
Air traffic is very complex and dynamic and so a flight plan describes expectations but actual times and other data (speed, altitude, etc) can differ when the actual flight procedes. Many decisions are made based on these plans and so they strive to be as accurate as possible.

Indeed, I understand that they are estimates and many factors might affect the actual times but I wanted to know what they were estimates of.  For example, scheduled at 14:00, leaves the gate at 13:50, and leaves the ground at 14:10.  Is it early or late?

Estimate of the plane moving away from the departure gate and stopping at the arrival gate. That's what I thought I wrote on the first sentence above.

Sorry, no criticism of your answer was intended.  I was just acknowledging the points that you made.

OK. Understood. In the case of your example, the flight is intuitively early to depart. Once leaving a gate, flights queue for their turn to take off and so it is normal that the lift-off is after the timed departure. In busy airports, that makes little difference since the flight could wait longer in the queue. Same with arrivals, when a plane lands early, it often then waits for the gate to be cleared and prepared. On the flip-side being late has a cascade effect and other flights and airport operations.


Does the scheduled departure time refer to leaving the gate, leaving the ground, or something else?

Typically it's when the cabin door closes or when the parking brakes are disengaged.

Similarly, does the scheduled arrival time refer to the landing, arrival at the gate, or something else?

Typically it's when the parking brakes are set.
Parking brakes are a popular choice since they can be tracked automatically and it has only limited amount of wiggle room for interpretation. "Gate arrival" and "Gate departure" can mean different things to different people. This is important since the exact definition can have legal and regulatory consequences (pilot hours, delay compensation, final decision authority, etc.)
Airlines determine these times simply by running statistics. They track the time on every route and look at the distribution of actual flight times (as defined above). They then choose a time so that maybe 80% will be on time and 90% within 10-15 minutes of on-time (depending on the shape of the distribution)
It's NOT the average or median flight time: otherwise half of the flights would be late. In fact its quite "normal" for a flight to be early. This also plays a factor in airlines setting minimum connection times which can sometimes feel ridiculously low.

I think I read somewhere that parking brakes also determine the number of flight hours for the pilots, which is the basis for their pay.

@NateEldredge yes, depends a bit on the aircraft type and operator. But generally either engine start/shutdown or brakes release/set determine registered flight hours (and aircraft rental fees in case you're paying for the aircraft by the hour).

For the purposes of EU261/UK261 legislation, the arrival time is the time that the airplane door is opened.  This will generally be at least a few minutes after the park brake is set.


What do scheduled flight times refer to?

Scheduled departure time from the gate and scheduled arrival time at the gate.
E.g., see Horizon Flight 2375, scheduled departure time is 4:15 pm:
https://www.alaskaair.com/status/2375/2024-04-29a

and looking at the details, that matches the scheduled departure time from the gate on https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/QXE2375/history/20241009/2325Z/KGEG/KSFO:


In the very specific context of EU's Air Passenger Rights during flight delays, the question was conclusively answered by the court ruling in Case C-452/13 (Germanwings GmbH v Ronny Henning). They list four possible definitions of "arrival time" that exist in various IATA and national air traffic regulations:

(a) the time that the aircraft lands on the runway ("touchdown");
(b) the time that the aircraft reaches its parking position and the parking brakes are engaged or the chocks have been applied ("in-block time");
(c) the time that the aircraft door is opened;
(d) a time defined by the parties in the context of party autonomy

And then rule that definition (c) applies when deciding whether the delay was large enough to trigger EU261 compensation:

... Articles 2, 5 and 7 of Regulation No 261/2004 must be interpreted as meaning that the concept of 'arrival time', which is used to determine the length of the delay to which passengers on a flight have been subject, refers to the time at which at least one of the doors of the aircraft is opened, the assumption being that, at that moment, the passengers are permitted to leave the aircraft.

